# Get the complete HTML color picker box in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am using the HTML color picker and I am facing one issue in the Google Chrome browser. In Chrome, some part of the color selection popup is missing, mostly defined colors. This is the current output of the color picker in Chrome.

[image]

And if I disable the Chrome web platform control updated UI from `chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh`
I will get the complete picker. This is what I wanted. I have added the needed color picker design here.

[image]

How can I get this color picker without any changes in the Chrome flag settings?